# How to combine multiple lines of code into one line of code?

Tags: c

The demo code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEMO(array) demo(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

typedef struct Demo {
    const char *msg;
} Demo;

void demo(Demo list[], size_t list_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", list[i].msg);
    }
}

int main() {
    Demo d[] = {
        {"Hello World"},
        {"Hello World"}
    };

    DEMO(d);
}
```

I want to merge the code in the main function, the way I imagine the merge is like this:

```c
DEMO((Demo []){
  {"Hello World"},
  {"Hello World"}
});
```

I remember seeing this kind of syntactic sugar in an open source project once, but I can't remember which project it was.

Comment: It seems you're looking for a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Comment: OT: Change `printf("%s\n", list[i].msg);` to `puts( list[ i ].msg );`

Comment: @Fe2O3: Why? Because it's marginally more efficient? The `printf` is fine.

Comment: There is a fine line between "syntactic sugar" and "code obfuscation". What you are asking for seems to be the latter.

Comment: @MOehm Why? Because the reader doesn't have to pause to "examine" whether or not there's something special going on in a nonexistent format specifier (in this trivial example shown.)

Comment: The OP's suggested solution isn't significantly shorter.

Comment: @Fe2O3: I know what you want to say, but I find it strange that you went out of your way to post an OT comment about it. Never mind, that's probably how SO works. There, you even got an upvote for it.

Comment: @MOehm OP was seeking to streamline and "compact" code a tiny bit. Jus' tryina help out in my own way.  Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: To streamline get rid of the single-member `struct` and use an array of pointers. Also would be easier to read - no need to look up what a `Demo` is.

Comment: “Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.” (Martin Fowler)

Comment: It is possible to write efficient code that spans multiple lines. It is possible to write efficient code that spans multiple lines. It is possible to write efficient code that spans multiple lines.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed invoke the macro with a compound literal argument, but you should be more careful in the macro definition to parenthesize all instances of its argument in the expansion, except as function arguments: `sizeof(array[0])` causes a syntax error for the argument `(Demo[]){{"Hello World"}, {"Hello World"}}`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEMO(array) demo(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]))

typedef struct Demo {
    const char *msg;
} Demo;

void demo(Demo list[], size_t list_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", list[i].msg);
    }
}

int main() {
    DEMO((Demo[]){{"Hello World"}, {"Hello World"}});
}
```

With the posted definition, you can still invoke the macro with the compound literal, but it must be parenthesized to ensure proper evaluation:

```
    DEMO( ( (Demo[]){ {"Hello World"}, {"Hello World"}} ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DEMO(((Demo[]){{"Hello World"},{"Hello World"}}));
```